# How to parse string of objects into javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I get from db this string:

```
{ from: 15.00, to: 16.00 },
{ from: 16.00, to: 17.00 },
{ from: 17.00, to: 18.00 },
{ from: 18.00, to: 19.00 }
```

It is a string and json.parse not work in this case. Is it possible to convert this string to regular js object?

Comment: Why is it not returning a valid JavaScript code? Adding [ and ] would make it work....

Comment: This is an array elements, it needs to be in square brackets i.e. `[`<elements>`]`, then you can parse it to json

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Line-delimited_JSON? Although it's not even proper JSON (missing quotes).

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current database output isn't parsable because it isn't considered valid JSON. You have a few options to fix this issue:

1. Store your string in your database as a stringified object so that when you need to parse it, it can be done easily.
2. Use regex to reformat your string so that it is parsable using `JSON.parse`. This involves making each key a string.
3. You can "loosely" parse your JSON. However, this isn't recommended as it opens your javascript up to injection attacks and other vulnerabilities.

*Reformatting your string:*

```js
const str = "{ from: 15.00, to: 16.00 },{ from: 16.00, to: 17.00 },{ from: 17.00, to: 18.00 },{ from: 18.00, to: 19.00 }",
parsable = str.replace(/(\w+):/g, '"$1":'),

obj = JSON.parse("[" +parsable +"]");
console.log(obj);
```

*"Loosely" parsing your JSON with a Function constructor:* - (Not recommended)

```js
const str = "{ from: 15.00, to: 16.00 },{ from: 16.00, to: 17.00 },{ from: 17.00, to: 18.00 },{ from: 18.00, to: 19.00 }",

obj = (Function("return [" + str + "]"))();
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with my answer?

Comment: No. I don't see any reason to downvote it

Comment: Thx a lot mate! Works great

Answer (score 0):

It is already parsed in JavaScript JSON syntax, you just need to enclose it in "[]" square braces. and you can directly access it as it is already parsed. You can test for first object using...

```js
  objArray=[ 
      { from: 15.00, to: 16.00 },
      { from: 16.00, to: 17.00 },
      { from: 17.00, to: 18.00 },
      { from: 18.00, to: 19.00 } 
    ];
console.log("From : " + objArray[0].from + " To : " + objArray[0].to);
```

Comment: OP says he's getting a string, so no, it is not "*already parsed in JavaScript*".

Comment: then it isn't a string even because nothing is escaped(thoroughly special chars), am i right..?

Comment: OP posted the contents of the string, not a string literal.