# Is there possibility to create an array with objects from string with curly braces imitating object?

Tags: javascript

I have a string, which looks like that:

```
"{ dataField: 'id', allowEditing: false },{ dataField: 'customer', allowEditing: false },{ dataField: 'type', allowEditing: false },{ dataField: 'weightMax', allowEditing: false },{ dataField: 'weightMin', allowEditing: false }"
```

I'm wondering about the way to parse this string to array of objects.
The result I'm expecting is an array which looks like that:

```
[{ dataField: 'id', allowEditing: false }, { dataField: 'customer', allowEditing: false }, { dataField: 'type' }, { dataField: 'weightMax' }, { dataField: 'weightMin'}]
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If your string were standard JSON, it would be easy. However, it is not.

Comment: You could use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) or [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function), but usually you shouldn't

Comment: There are a few options outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54868074/5648954) (option 1 is preferred).